# Is it possible to grant access for someone using python to only fetch data from mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Someone is trying to connect python with my mysql using mysql.connector.connect(), is it possible that I only grant him the access of fetching data from my database, meaning that he cannot in any way meddle with my original data.

Comment: Create a database user who only has the `read` privilege.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, You can with below command in console**

Login with root privileges to your MySQL or MariaDB console execute below command for a specific database.

```
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON DATA_BASE_NAME.* TO USER_WITH_READ_ONLY_ACCESS@SPECIFIC_HOST IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**For Example:**

**Database:** database_test

**User:** user_readonly

**Host:** localhost

**Password:** user_pass_123

```
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON database_test.* TO user_readonly@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'user_pass_123';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```